# Why Kodos is not part of the available packages in Ubuntu Quantal 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, repository, editor, regex

I'm running the 64-bit edition of Ubuntu Quantal and I've used extensively Kodos, a user friendly regex editor.

It seems that for some reasons, this package has been deleted from the Ubuntu Quantal repositories. (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/kodos/2.4.9-6.3ubuntu1)

Is someone aware about what was the motive of such decision ?
For those who, like me, used this utility, what choices are we left with ?

If possible, I'd like to avoid any compilation nor the need to virtualize a previous Ubuntu release just to use one utility.

Thank you in advance to shed some light on this point.

Answer (score 4):

Old deps for python-qt3 et al were replaced with -qt4, you can either [update your repository refs](https://launchpad.net/~phobie/+archive/updates) or install manually (make sure to resolve the deps).

Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7.0.50~), python, pyqt4-dev-tools.

http://ppa.launchpad.net/phobie/updates/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kodos/kodos_2.4.9+20120813-0ubuntu0px1.dsc

Here's the .deb pkg: http://ppa.launchpad.net/phobie/updates/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kodos/kodos_2.4.9+20120813-0ubuntu0px1_all.deb

Comment: There's also RegExr, http://askubuntu.com/a/31261/108266. And of course the classical GNU tools--grep/egrep, sed, awk. Quite much adorable for this matter and actually inherent in design are python and perl. There's also vim. Oh, and certainly there are countless javascript or cgi tools online. So you still have got a bunch of alternatives, besides the subject-matter application, needless to say.

Comment: the classical tools aren't designed to be easy regex debuggers. Besides, the various tools you listed have several different regex syntaxes so won't really help you with python regex now will they... I miss Kodos, so pleasant to use.

Comment: @kaleissin that's right, there are slight syntax differences that are well covered in various comparison charts. Install kodos if you like it, it shouldn't take you longer than a minute unless you compile, in which case it would take some 5 minutes. If I reckon right, kodos doesn't work with recursive patterns, does it? Quite a simple upgrade if it doesn't. On codeplex some guys published their implementation of a regex tester with a GUI in C#, other than the GUI which is either WinForms or WPF the engine which isn't a mystery should work well with Mono.

Answer (score 1):

**Kiki** is still in quantal but is a lot less advanced.

> Kiki is a free environment for regular expression testing (ferret). It
>   allows you to write regexes and test them against your sample text,
>   providing extensive output about the results.

With Kiki the expression is evaluated when you press the "Evaluate"-button while with Kodos the evaluation is real-time.

I've built Kodos for raring now, see [ppa:kaleissin/monty](https://launchpad.net/~kaleissin/+archive/monty), and I'm planning to build it for any future ubuntu I use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is an equivalent but I used [regexxer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=regexxer) in the not too distant past.

Comment: Thanks for your proposition, regexxer is a valuable tool, but what I was looking for is the kind of ability for instant regex debugging and copy-paste offered by Kodos. I've got the impression that Kodos relies on some deprecated python packages ? Hence this might explain why such tool is no more available.